# If 2nd test is failed cypress will stop the execution but i need to continue to run other tests? in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have 3 test cases when 2nd test case is failed it should not stop execution there only. It Should run further tests/ It should continue the test

Comment: means when i use assertion for the all 3 test cases.
if 1st assertion is failed it should run further test-case in cypress ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create that behaviour by creating various `it()`'s in your testfile. The syntax would look like this:

```
describe({
  it({
    // assertion 1
  })
  it({
    // assertion 2
  })
  it({
    // assertion 3
  })
})
```

If an `it()` fails it stops that it, but it will continue with the other `it()`'s.

Comment: No I have tried. Actually when it fails automatically it ll redirect to home page and again I need to give URL, user name, password and login for each test so without giving those things can we run the the all the tests if any one test is fails.

Comment: in that case you can't. Apparently the application, which you are testing, has the behaviour to redirect to the home page. Cypress can't do anything about that.

What you can de is the `it()` as described above and add a `beforeEach()` function which logs in for every test. That will result in executing the other tests, but the side effect is that it logs in for every test.